# touch up outside range

Tags: ios, touch

How to change the distance for triggering touch up outside method?
UIButton's touch up outside method only fire when touch up location is about 100 pixels away from the button, as i can see the button's highlight changed when drag from inside about 100 pixels to outside.
Is there a way to shorten the distance?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

could you please try

```
- (IBAction)btnDragged:(id)button withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *t = [[event touchesForView:yourButtonView] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [t locationInView:self.view];
    //NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchLocation));

    if (your condition, using CGPoint to check for shorten distance, compare your button location and touchLocation) {
      //fire some stuff
    }
}
```

hope it help, please give me a feedback, so I know what's going on, then I can edit my code to help you, Good luck :).

remarkable: event will contain the coordinates

UPDATE:// according to your comment below
please try, in if condition, you need to check that what kind of class of your end point

Assume that you want to shorten to 50 pixels away from button, 
so the condition should be similar to this.

```
if ( fabsf(yourButton.frame.x - touchLocation.x) <= 50 && fabsf(yourButton.frame.y - touchLocation.y) <= 50 ) {

    UIView *v = [self.view hitTest:touchLocation withEvent:nil];
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) //check that it is button B or not
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

hope it help :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. in fact, I want to implement a slide in button operation; first I touch a button A,then button B show up some where, then I hold the touch, slide to button B, when I touch up inside B, I want to trigger my method. the problem is , the touch up inside B method can't be triggered, my only way to solve the problem is to check in button A's touch up outside method. but it seems that  the outside range is not what i expected.